# How do I organize an Ubuntu party or get together?

Tags: community, locoteams, contributing

I would like organize some Ubuntu party with my school, but how to improve Ubuntu with our time? (easily)

Comment: "improve ubuntu with our team?" -explain?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There are tons of ways that an organized group of people can contribute to Ubuntu. Here are some of mine:

- [LoCo Activities](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/LoCoTeamKnowledgeBase) - formal teams in Ubuntu are called Local Teams (LoCo), they have a ton of information with good ideas on their [wiki page](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/LoCoTeams). You can find if there's an existing LoCo team in [the directory](http://loco.ubuntu.com/). I recommend you contact them and let them know that you're ready to start planning events at your school.
- Throw a [release party](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/BuildingCommunity/RunningReleaseParty?action=show&redirect=LoCoRunningReleaseParty)!!
- You can run an [Ubuntu Jam](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Jams)
- You can run an [Ubuntu Hour](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Hour)
- And of course, you can all particiapte on Ask Ubuntu by asking more questions and answering them - the site is still relatively new and we could always use questions that new users are running into so we can help build a good list of answers.

Comment: Ok, thanks, we will first do some mapping for OpenStreetMap, then we will search for bugs and report them.
And if it become boring, we will do some "mini-apps" with [quickly](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Quickly).

Comment: Had the same question today. I like the Ubuntu Jam and Ubuntu Hour ideas for what I want to do in my city.