# Ubuntu Release Party Support

Tags: community

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I organize an Ubuntu party or get together?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/23264/how-do-i-organize-an-ubuntu-party-or-get-together)

I wanna held Ubuntu Release Party in my City.
How can i get support from canonical?
such as Ubuntu DVD or merch?

Answer (score 0):

What you must do is create a Ubuntu LoCo, or to find one in your city if it has one already. LoCo stands for Local Community team. The LoCo is the one that will organise Ubuntu events in the city, and are officially recognised by Canonical. A LoCo can get support from Canonical, **but most of the time support will come from your community.**

If you want to join a LoCo Team, it's easy! Just [find a team](http://loco.ubuntu.com/teams/) in your area and click the 'Join This Team!' link at the top of their page.

If you are not able to find a LoCo Team in your area and want to create one, take a look at the [LoCo Team HowTo](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/LoCoTeamHowto) for more information on setting up a LoCo Team